# Pass - Fail question

Tags: bash

I am writing a command which is given below.

```
if ["$avg" -ge "80"]; then
echo "PASS"
else
echo "FAIL"
```

I am getting an error like:

```
x.0000000000000000 integer expression expected 
and the result of if -else statement is always wrong.
```

Pls help and suggest necessary changes.

Comment: You are comparing strings.

Comment: Please post the ***exact*** content of your scriptlet. When I run it as it is shown I get `Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "fi")`. When I add the missing `fi` at the end (given `avg=100`) I get `[100: not found` followed by `FAIL`. Nothing about `x.0000000000000000`. If you want exact answers, please post exact questions. Especially in this case _space does matter_.

Comment: Be aware that bash can only do integer arithmetic, so if $avg is somehow a float value, you'll have to truncate it.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

# .........
# ........

if [ $avg -ge 80 ]
then
  echo "PASS"
else
  echo "FAIL"
fi
```

---

As *steeldriver* suggested, use [`shellcheck`](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck). You can install it with

```
sudo apt install shellcheck
```

Use it with

```
shellcheck myscript.sh
```

In your case you will get following output:

```
In myscript.sh line 1:
if ["$avg" -ge "80"]; then
^-- SC1009: The mentioned parser error was in this if expression.
   ^-- SC1035: You need a space after the [ and before the ].
   ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this test expression.
                    ^-- SC1020: You need a space before the ].
                    ^-- SC1072: Missing space before ]. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

Comment: Cool. Wasn't aware _shellcheck_ can be _installed_. I just knew their [website](https://www.shellcheck.net/). Perfect!